# Searching through an array of objects, properties of the objects being undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, dynamic-arrays

Sample of javascript code:

```
function a() {
    this.array1 = [];
    this.addToArray = function(name) {
        this.array1.push(new b(name));
        return true;
    }
    this.searchForName = function(name) {
        for(var i in this.array1) {
            alert(i.name);
        }
    }
    function b(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I included this javascript file in an html document. Inside script tags of an html document I have this code:

```
var myObject = new a();
myObject.addToArray("test1");
myObject.searchForName("test1");
```

Running this code, I would expect an alert with `"test1"` in it to pop up, but instead it pops up as undefined. The debugger in Chrome, however, shows that there is an array inside of myObject with an item 0 that has a name of `"test1"`. When I use breakpoints to test the code, it shows that at the moment the alert is called, *i.name is undefined*. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `name` property on the `i` number instead of in member `i` of `this.array`.

So:

```
i.name
```

should be:

```
this.array1[i].name
```

Result is:

```
this.searchForName = function(name) {
    for(var i in this.array1) {
             // get it from this array1
        alert(this.array1[i].name);
    }
}
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/seNxD/

Also, it is not a good idea to use a `for-in` statement if you're only interested in numeric indices. A `for` statement is the one to use since you're not enumerating.

Comment: Do not use `for ... in` when looping over the elements of an array.

Comment: @mhitza: Isn't that what my answer says? ;o)

Comment: Lol, dunno how I missed the last sentence :)

Comment: @mhitza: Well, it would have been better of me to correct the loop as well in the solution. Being lazy I guess. :o)

Answer (score 2):

Never loop over an array with `for...in` ([MDC documentation describes *why*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)). Use a normal `for` loop:

```
for(var i = this.array1.length;i--;) {
    alert(this.array1[i].name);
}
```

`for...in` loops over the *keys* of an object anyway, which would be the indices for an array. Hence the loop body for a `for...in` loop must look exactly the same as for the `for` loop shown above.

For example, you would use `for...in` if you have this:

```
var obj = {foo: 'bar', answer: '42'};
for(var key in obj) {
    alert(key + " is " + obj[key]);
}
```

*Further note:* It is convention to start the name of constructor functions with a capital letter.

Comment: @TheDog: No, the primary reason for `for...in` is to loop over object properties.

Comment: +1 You did a better job than I in dealing with the error prone loop.